# EF Convention to manage entity values, is it possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that we can manage the way EF deal with metadata using conventions, I´d like to know if its possible to change entity values using a kind of conventions, for example: I have an existing database and all varchar´s columns are filled with spaces at the end, is it possible trim all string values when I select the entities?

Comment: Can't you just run a SQL script that trims the data in the database? I don't think you can achieve this with custom conventions.

Answer (score 0):

> have an existing database and all varchar´s columns are filled with spaces at the end, is it possible trim all string values when I select the entities?

Yes, you could modify *.tt file (one of entity framework files, which is used to generate entities).

My code to Trim and null strings (replace that function in *.tt file):

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{       
    string typ = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage);

    if (typ == "string")
    {
        string prop = "_" + _code.Escape(edmProperty);
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "\r\n\tprivate string " + prop + ";\r\n\t" +
            "{0} {1} {2} \r\n\t{{\t\t{3}{6} {4}{5} \t}}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),

            "\r\n\t\tset" +
            "\r\n\t\t{" + 
            "\r\n\t\t\t" + prop + " = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value.Trim();" +
            "\r\n\t\t}" +
            "\r\n",

            "\r\n\t\tget" +
            "\r\n\t\t{" + 
            "\r\n\t\t\treturn " + prop + ";" +
            "\r\n\t\t}");
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "\r\n\t{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I´m using Code-First, is there a way to achieve the same behavior in codefirst ?

Comment: If you use code-first, then you 'generate' your properties. So you should add to your getter `return _value.Trim()'`. I know that you'd probably like to set this behavior globally, but I don't know a way to this.